# Maximising the distance between $n$ points in a 2d region

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computer-science, computational-complexity

I've been looking into the problem of computing the problem of placing $n$ points on a finite rectangular region of size $w \times h$ in a 2d plane so as to minimise the function $\sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{d_{i,j}} $, where $d_{i,j}$ is the euclidean distance between point $i$ and $j$. So far I've not had any success in working out the complexity of this problem, so I was hoping to look at the problem of placing the points such that the average distance is maximised between each pair of points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For the problem to be well defined, do you have to specify the 2D region? Was it a circle? Was it a square?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The area is an arbitrary rectangle of width $w$ and height $h$, I've updated the question to mention that.

Comment: maximizing $S=\sum_{i,j}d_{ij}$ is not going to be useful for the original problem you have. This is because $S$ is maximized when all of the points are distributed evenly at the corners. Say if you have 8 points, then $S$ is maximized when two points are placed at each corner. In that case some of the $d_{ij}$ are zero which won't be allowed in the original problem.

Comment: @DuncanAdamson Did this come from a electrostatic problem (minimizing the potential energy) or something else in physics with the same mathematical formulation?

Comment: When one of the dimension is much larger (the rectangle being essentially a thin strip), then the physical intuition dictates that the points should `line up' uniformly with regular distance in between (hitting both ends). When $w \approx h$ that the rectangle is roughly a square, then (my personal) physical intuition suggests the points form a regular lattice that also covers the boundary.

Comment: Under the rationale laid out just above, there's at least one phase transition when the ratio of the two sides varies. That is, there are more than one solutions, depending on $\frac{w}h$. The $w \ll h$ (or $w \gg h$) extreme is a stable configuration (equilibrium), and other configurations are at least semi-stable.

Comment: For a given rectangle, the type of regular lattice might also depend on n, switching between hexogonal-ish lattice and rectangluar lattice.

Comment: @Marco: Do you have a proof for this assertion?